# MediaPlayer crashes on setDataSource with R.raw audio

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm making an Audio Player app that will load some predefined audios from inside its `raw` resource folder.

I've sent the test APK for some people to test it, and it worked on 99% of the cases. But then, I started to get some crash reports on Crashlytics for **a single device**, the `OnePlus A5000`, running Android 8.1.0.

The stacktrace on crashlytics is as follows:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
       at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java)
       at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1270)
       at com.example.home.MediaPlayerHolder.loadMedia(MediaPlayerHolder.kt:56)
       at com.example.home.HomePresenter.playSound(HomePresenter.kt:26)
       at com.example.home.HomeFragment.onPlaySelected(HomeFragment.kt:178)
       at com.example.home.SoundItemAdapter$ViewHolder$bind$1.onClick(SoundItemAdapter.kt:30)
```

*package names were changed for privacy reasons*

This is happening almost every time he clicks on the sound item play button. It also happens on the first time he clicks on any sound item.

I've tried to reproduce this crash on some devices, all of then have API <= 25, but I had no success doing so. All of them ran without an issue. I'm clueless of the probable cause of this error, or even if it's an edge case problem, or if there's indeed something wrong with my code.

This is how I'm loading the audio on the `MediaPlayer`:

```
if (mediaPlayer?.isPlaying == true) {
    mediaPlayer?.release()
    mediaPlayer = null
}
if (mediaPlayer == null) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
}

val fileDescriptor = context.resources.openRawResourceFd(resource)
mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.fileDescriptor, fileDescriptor.startOffset, fileDescriptor.length)
fileDescriptor.close()
mediaPlayer?.prepare()
mediaPlayer?.start()
```

Comment: Please check this article, hope this can help you. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: Hey, thanks for the article, I'll take a look at it and perhaps try to make the player a foreground service. As of now it's running on the UI Thread, perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: yes this happen the issue, let me know if your problem will solve. Thanks.

Comment: I'll let you know, thanks!

Comment: Wellcome brother, If the information help your mark my answere as right one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was you can't start services in the background anymore after `API 26`. So you have to start ForegroundService above API 26.

Comment: Also remember, when you start a foreground service, you have about 5 seconds to launch a notification, otherwise the system kills your service with an exception. `serviceContext.StartForeground(123, mNotification);`